# Looping multiple arrays simultaneously

Tags: php

Doing a homework assignment and I'm not sure I can wrap my mind around how to go about this problem.  I have two arrays with the same amount of values:

```
$monthsShort = array("Jan", "Feb", ..., "Nov", "Dec");
$monthsLong = array("January", "February", ..., "November", "December");
```

I need a loop that will traverse both of them and generate output that looks like this:

> 1 Jan January
>
> 2 Feb February
>
> ...
>
> 12 Dec December

I'm just really not sure where to begin as I can't find a similar problem in my textbook.  I did find this: [Foreach loop with multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398618/foreach-loop-with-multiple-arrays), but I am not sure how/why it works.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of the example data you provided. Make sure the arrays are the same length!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
  $p = $i+1;
  echo "$p {$monthsShort[$i]} {$monthsLong[$i]}";
}
```

Comment: in case it matters: `echo $i+1;`

Answer (score 4):

You can get a single index of an array by using this syntax:

```
$myArray = array("Jan", "Feb", "etc.");
echo $myArray[0]; // prints "Jan"
echo $myArray[1]; // prints "Feb"
```

The only trick is that you want the indexes to be a variable too, which you can use a `for` loop for. This will print "JanFebetc.":

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    echo $myArray[$i];
}
```

Those two together should let you loop through both arrays at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

The example you have picked is for arrays *inside* arrays, you actually have two arrays you would like to iterate over at once. That's something different.

You can first combine both arrays with [`array_map`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_map) and then iterate over the new array:

```
$monthsShort = array("Jan", "Feb", '...', "Nov", "Dec");
$monthsLong = array("January", "February", '...', "November", "December");

$map = array_map(NULL, $monthsShort, $monthsLong);

foreach($map as $month => $value)
{
    list($short, $long) = $value;
    printf("%d %s %s\n", $month+1, $short, $long);
}
```

See the [demo](http://codepad.org/SoLijx3u). As often in programming, there are more than one solution to a problem, I choose `array_map` to easily iterate over one array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$index = 0;
foreach ($monthsShort as $month) {
    echo $index+1 . " " . $month . " " . $monthsLong[$index] . "\n";
    $index++;
}
```

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using a `for` loop, as you can see below:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++)
{
    printf("%d %s %s<br />\n", $i + 1, $monthsShort[$i], $monthsLong[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = '';
$count = count($monthsShort);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
  $output .= $i . ' ' . $monthsShort[$i] . ' ' . $monthsLong[$i] . '<br />';
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the count function to count the items in the array

```
<?php
    $monthsShort = array("Jan", "Feb", "Nov", "Dec");
    $monthsLong = array("January", "February", "November", "December");

    for($i=0;$i<count($monthsLong);$i++){
        echo $i." ".$monthsShort[$i]." ".$monthsLong[$i]."\n";
    }

?>
```

Outputs

```
0 Jan January
1 Feb February
2 Nov November
3 Dec December
```